# Application wide serial port utilisation

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am developing a WPF application in C# and am communicating with a serial device. Currently in the main window of my application I am displaying some information that I obtain by periodically reading lines from the serial device.

Sometimes I need to constantly receive and save data from the serial device to a file. I stop other methods that are utilizing the serial port (like the one that is periodically reading lines to display on the main window) so that the recording process is not interfered with. It can be cumbersome to manage access to the serial port across the application and so "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" is not uncommon.

In each method or window within the application that utilizes the serial device I define a new serial port, open it, read lines and then close and dispose it. I have read though that it is good practice to open the serial port when the application launches and close it when the application closes and I can see why this would be helpful with where I am getting to with this application. I have some questions though:

- Where should I define the serial port object?
- If I am calling the serial port object from more than one window or method am I creating more than one instance of the serial port object? Can you have more than one instance of a serial port object for just one physical serial port?
- If I had SerialPort.ReadLine() being called from two different methods (on two different threads), would one line go to one method and then the next line to the other method and repeat like that? How could I make all serial data go to both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a separate class to manage the SerialPort connection. It should have its own thread that reads from the serial port. It can then distribute the information it reads to the other places in your application. One good way to do this is using `Rx`. Make a singleton from this class and inject it into anywhere else in the application that needs it.

Using `Rx` you can subscribe to messages from the serial port as many times as you need to.

1. Create a class to manage the serial port:

   ```
   public class SerialPortManager
   {
     private SerialPort;
     private string comPort;
     Subject<string> messageBus = new Subject<string>();
     public IObservable<string> MessageBus => messageBus;
     private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

     public SerialPortManager(string comPort)
     {
        this.comport = comport;
     }

     public void Start()
     {
         ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(SerialDeviceThread);
         Thread t = new Thread(ts);
         t.IsBackground = true;
         t.Name = this.Name;
         t.Start();
     }

     private void SerialDeviceThread()
     {
         this.serialPort = new SerialPort(this.comPort, ...);
         while (true)
         {
             string line = this.serialPort.ReadLine();
             this.messageBus.OnNext(line);
         }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Create a singelton of this class somewhere:

   ```
   public static Lazy<SerialPortManager> SerialPortManager = 
     new Lazy<SerialPortManager>(x => {
           var sm = new SerialPortManager("COM2"); 
           sm.Start(); 
           return sm; 
      });
   ```

and elsewhere

```
SerialPortManager.Value.MessageBus.Subscribe( ...)
```

[This is still greatly simplified, I would have logic around the serial port to catch failures and recreate the port when it disconnects. I'd also use a dependency injection container (e.g. Autofac) rather than a static value.]

Comment: could you please elaborate on creating a separate class for the serial port and how I can make a singleton from this class and inject it wherever needed in the application. Or if you have any links to relevant documentation on what I just mentioned or about Rx. How is the first block of code you've provided used?

Comment: @thoward Elaboration added.

Comment: Thanks @IanMercer. How about retrieving the string after I have the subscribe statement? I'm struggling to find an example like this to give me a clue. Also do I need to make it a 'hot' observable as in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977(v=vs.103).aspx) so that subscribers on different threads receive the same string at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is an object managing access to your serial port.  This object would set up the port object once and start a new thread that would read lines continuously from the serial port, and fire an event when it has read the line.  Then your other application objects would attach delegates to that event when they want to be notified of data coming in from the serial port.  In that way, data from the serial port would always be broadcast to those who were interested.  Depending on your UI, you will have to use the Invoke() method on Dispatcher (for WPF) or on a Windows form object (for Windows forms) to make sure the event is fired from the UI thread so it can invoke UI methods correctly.